# DC Block after the Balance - what problems would that cause?

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, analog

I am building a radio receiver using the MAX2021 down converter. And I am building a down-conversion circuit similar to the reference design provided by the data sheet:
[image: differential IQ putting through a balance and converts into single ended signal]

My problem is that I only have two DC blocks. So I am trying to use my DC blocks after the balance, instead of before.

Would inputting a differential signal with DC bias into a balance severely impact the signal?

Thanks ahead if you know the answer.

Comment: If there is any DC offset at the input to the mixers will compromise LO or carrier rejection.

Comment: what's stopping you getting hold of two more capacitors?